# jQuery parent and child animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, parent, children

My code is like this and it's not working as expected.

```
function urSizeUp() {
 $('#someDiv', '#someDiv > div').animate({
  'width': '400px',
  'height': '100px'
 }, 500);
}

$('#someDiv').hover(urSizeUp);
```

The thing is to animate width and height for both parent and child elements.
Is it possible to do at once, or do i have to write another function?

#### Edit

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50e1ohgk/).

Notice that if you remove the second (or first) selector from both of the functions it works.

Comment: it should work. what is the html like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few too many quotes in the selector :

```
function urSizeUp() {

$('#someDiv, #someDiv > div').animate({'width': 400, 'height': 100}, 500);
}

$('#someDiv').hover(urSizeUp);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xboWoZ

Edit - didn't see the fiddle at first...

https://jsfiddle.net/50e1ohgk/1/